# How I associate an Image with a String in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm working on an Xcode app that randomly displays an image, but I want it to display a certain amount of text with each different image.  I'm unsure on how to load all of these 40 strings (I have 40 different images) and how would I make sure that each image is associated with its own string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without more context, it's not easy to help you. The answer could be a dictionary, an array of tuples or something more complex involving Core Data

Comment: You should structure your data and create two properties. One for the image location or is name if it is located in your Bundle and one for the associated string.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar thing, I just made a dictionary like this with the name of the image and its corresponding text:

```
var imageDict = ["image1":"This is image one", "image2": "this is image two"...]
```

The images are in my assets folder. So when I display image 1 it is simply:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: Array(imageDict)[0].key)
imageText.text = Array(imageDict)[0].value
```

If you are randomly selecting an image then you can randomly generate a number from 0 to 40 i.e.

```
let randomIntFrom0To40 = Int.random(in: 1..<40)
```

and whatever number it outputs you can use on the dictionary like above and you will always get the right text with the right image.

or you could access by name:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
imageView.text = imageDict["image1"]
```

Then your image and its text are paired.

But this is one example as your question is vague there may be a different solution. In this case, I assume you have all the text and the images you need and can create the Dictionary like above in your code.

Comment: I get the error:|| Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]' with an index of type 'Int'    || when I try to update the image and the text

Comment: @YachtSamba I updated my answer, I missed out that we need to specify whether its the Key or Value when accessing the dictionary, the update should work for you.